# Is <![CDATA[ content ]]> are show when xml parse

Tags: objective-c, xml, cdata

Please tell me when I add in the xml while writing `<![CDATA[ content ]]>` then when I view the source in Mozilla Firefox then it shows `<![CDATA[ content ]]>` and when I parse this xml then is it escape or it comes? Please tell me! I want to parse this xml in objective C?

Comment: What does parsing it in your Objective-C application have to do with viewing it in Firefox? And more importantly why are you tagging this PHP when you're talking about Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of CDATA is to mark things that shouldn't be parsed. Anything you put within `<![CDATA[...]]>` will not be parsed.